# Painful Generics, Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

Tags: c#, generics

Here is my code:

```
class BinaryTree<T> 
{
    private node<T> Head;
    public class node<T> 
    {
     public T Data;
     public node<T> right;
     public node<T> left;
     public node<T> parent;
    ...
    }
    ...
    private void insert(ref T data, node<T> parent, ref node<T> currentChild) 
    {
    ...
        {
            if (currentChild.Data >= data) insert(ref data, currentChild, ref currentChild.right);
            else insert(ref data, currentChild, ref currentChild.left);
        }
     }
}
```

Above at point `if (currentChild.Data >= data)` I am getting error :

> Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

What do I do to resolve the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The classic solutions to this problem are (1) to make `T` [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx), or (2) to use an [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) or a functor to your class.

(1)

```
class BinaryTree<T> where T : Comparable<T> ...
```

(2)

```
class BinaryTree<T> {
    private node<T> Head;
    private readonly IComparer<T> comparer;
    public BinaryTree(IComparer<T> comparer) {
        this.comparer = comparer;
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: can you please explain how does that where T : IComparable<T> tells the compiler that T implements IComparable ?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis That is a condition on the generic type T: it tells the compiler that `BinaryTree<T>` *cannot* be created, unless `T` implements `IComparable<T>`.

Comment: So what if I instantiate T with user defined types which doesn't implements (inherits) `IComparable<T>` , it breaks the policy still? doesn't it?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis The compiler is going to catch it, and the code will not compile.

Answer (score 12):

You need to specify that T implements IComparable so that you can compare:

```
class BinaryTree<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    ...
    public class node<T> where T : IComparable<T> ...
    ...
    if (currentChild.Data.CompareTo(data) >= 0) ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: But I don't want to use that `currentChild.Data.CompareTo(data) >= 0` notation, Any other method?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about C#, but in Java you would need to have an instance of a generic Comparator class, parametrized with the types you want to compare. This generic class provided a compareTo() function which would be implemented in a way that allows for comparison of the two types.

Answer (score 1):

T should be a type that implements IComparable and then use its compareto to method instead of >=.  Operator overloading is another option if you still want to support >=.

Answer (score 1):

While some people suggest using IComparable, I would suggest using an `IComparer<T>` instead, which should be stored in a field of your tree.  One of the constructors for your tree should accept an `IComparer<T>`, which should be stored in your field.  The other should probably set the `IComparer<T>` field to `Comparer<T>.InvariantDefault()`.  Consumers of your tree will thus be able to choose how things within the tree will be sorted.  Note that if an `IComparer<T>` is supplied when a class is constructed, there's no real reason that `T` should have to implement `IComparable<T>`.  It might be nice to enforce a compile-time requirement that `T` implement `IComparer<T>` when constructing an tree without specifying a compare method, but there's no way to do that without requiring a somewhat awkward syntax like `treeInstance = factoryClass.Create<myType>()` which would create an instance of `treeClass<myType>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing Data is of type `Object` and thus does not automatically allow for an >= operation.
You need to add a constraint for T so that it is IComparable

```
class BinaryTree<T> where T : IComparable
```