# Brain-breaking error using generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm trying to make Universal `Repository pattern` base class from which will be implemented members. Here is a code:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntity, TType> : IRepository<TEntity, TType>
    where TEntity : EntityBase<TType>
{
    public IAdNetMsSqlContext Context { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TEntity> DbSet { get; set; }

    public RepositoryBase(IAdNetMsSqlContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> Get(TType id)
    {
        //!!! Here is an error
        return DbSet.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
    }
    ....
}
```

And I get the error:

```
   Error    1   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TType' and    `'TType' .... AdNet.Common.Base
```

In the line:

```
   return DbSet.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
```

I dont know what to think. TType is for sure equal to TType.

Thx for any advance!

Comment: What is `TType` intended to be at this point?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001332/painful-generics-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-t-and-t

Comment: It should be generic type of identity of Entity, like `Int32, Int64, Guid...`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- You're trying to return an `IQueryable<TEntity>` when `FirstOrDefault` will only return a single `TEntity`, so you should change the return type
- You're trying to use `==` which isn't allowed on unconstrained generics. You could constraint `TType` to be a class, at which point it would perform reference equality, but that's probably not you want given the examples you've given.

Given that this is going to be translated to SQL anyway (so you don't need to worry about the impact of boxing) I'd just convert it to use `Equals`:

```
public TEntity Get(TType id)
{
    return DbSet.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id.Equals(id));
}
```

Or can't you just use [`DbSet<TEntity>.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) in the first place?

```
public TEntity Get(TType id)
{
    return DbSet.Find(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might know that `TType` is obviously equal to `TType`, but what the compiler doesn't know is whether any arbitrary, unconstrained `TType` will have an `==` operator (aka `op_Equality`).

Can you use `Equals` instead?

```
return DbSet.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id.Equals(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

It just happens that both generics share the same name: TType

From a compiler point of view it does not realize that e.Id is the same as id and more than likely you could write some code that would make the scenario true.

I am assuming that the comparison for TType checks that it is physically the same object and not 2 objects with the same values. If you cast both to Object the comparison should work